# REST API with node-rtsp-stream NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, streaming, rtsp

I am trying to stream a RTSP in HTML5 pages using node-rtsp-stream NPM. Here I can see the live stream in HTML page. But the thing is when I try to do REST API with this it throws `TypeError: stream is not a constructor`. when I call my post method first time its working properly. when I try to do the same again it throws error.

here is my API:

```
RTSPRouter.post('/getPreview', (req, res) => {
    // stream.mpeg1Muxer.kill();

    stream = new stream({
        name: 'name',
        streamUrl: req.body.RTSPURL,
        wsPort: 9999,
        ffmpegOptions: {
            '-r': 30
        }
    })
    res.send(stream)
})
```

API for Kill :

```
RTSPRouter.get('/killPreview', (req, res) => {
     process.kill(req.body.pid1)
    stream.prototype.stop()// this method also not working

})
```

Even I killed the stream alone using the PID it's throwing the same error.

Kindly help me to fix this problem, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you're getting a typeError because you haven't imported Stream.
Your code should look like this:

```
  Stream = require("node-rtsp-stream");
  stream = new Stream({
    name: "name",
    streamUrl: "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov",
    wsPort: 9999,
    ffmpegOptions: {
      // options ffmpeg flags
      "-stats": "", // an option with no neccessary value uses a blank string
      "-r": 30, // options with required values specify the value after the key
    },
  });
  res.send(stream);
```

Also don't forget to run `npm install node-rtsp-stream`.

Answer (score 0):

After a few days I found the answer for this question.
You should not create stream like this:

```
 var stream = require('node-rtsp-stream')
 stream = new stream({
        name: 'name',
        streamUrl: req.body.RTSPURL,
        wsPort: 9999,
        ffmpegOptions: {
            '-r': 30
        }
    })
```

Instead of this, try the below code:

```
    var stream = require('node-rtsp-stream')
    var streamObj;
    streamObj = new stream({
            name: 'name',
            streamUrl: req.body.RTSP,
            wsPort: 9999,
            ffmpegOptions: { // options ffmpeg flags
                '-stats': '', // an option with no neccessary value uses a blank string
                '-r': 30 // options with required values specify the value after the key
            }
        })
```

The actual error is that I had imported a stream with the name `stream`, and tried to initiate the stream with same variable name `stream`. You have to use a different variable name to initialize the stream. In my case I used `streamobj`.